# Python RE ( In a word to check first letter is case sensitive and rest all case insensitive)

Tags: python, regex

In the below case i want to match string "Singapore" where "S" should always be capital and rest of the words may be in lower or in uppercase. but in the below string "s" is in lower case and it gets matched in search condition. can any body let me know how to implement this?

```
       import re       
            st = "Information in sinGapore "

            if re.search("S""(?i)(ingapore)" , st):
                print "matched"

Singapore => matched  
sIngapore => notmatched  
SinGapore => matched  
SINGAPORE => matched
```

Comment: "S" Should always be capital.

Comment: @wooble -- No, it should be `S[iI][nN][gG][aA][pP][oO][rR][eE]`, but that's super ugly... There's gotta be a better way...

Comment: Err, right. Reading fail.

Comment: @Wooble it is not satisfying all the conditions. there might be upper case letters after "S"

Comment: @eyquem Can you help me in this?

Comment: I improved a lot the code and edited my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to set a GV code according to the catched phrase (unique name or several name blank separated, I know that), there must be a step in which the code is choosen in a dictionary according to the catched phrase.
So it's easy to make a profit of this step to perform the test on the first letter (must be uppercased) or the first name in the phrase that no regex is capable of.

I choosed certain conditions to constitute the test. For example, a dot in a first name is not mandatory, but uppercased letters are. These conditions will be easily changed at need.

#### EDIT 1

```
import re

def regexize(cntry):
    def doot(x):
        return '\.?'.join(ch for ch in x) + '\.?'
    to_join = []
    for c in cntry:
        cspl = c.split(' ',1)
        if len(cspl)==1: # 'Singapore','Austria',...
            to_join.append('(%s)%s'
                           % (doot(c[0]), doot(c[1:])))
        else: # 'Den LMM','LMM Den',....
            to_join.append('(%s) +%s'
                           % (doot(cspl[0]),
                              doot(cspl[1].strip(' ').lower())))
    pattern = '|'.join(to_join).join('()')
    return re.compile(pattern,re.I)

def code(X,CNTR,r = regexize):
    r = regexize(CNTR)
    for ma in r.finditer(X):
        beg = ma.group(1).split(' ')[0]
        if beg==ma.group(1):
            GV = countries[beg[0]+beg[1:].replace('.','').lower()] \
                 if beg[0].upper()==beg[0] else '- bad match -'
        else:
            try:
                k = (ki for ki in countries.iterkeys()
                     if beg.replace('.','')==ki.split(' ')[0]).next()
                GV = countries[k]
            except StopIteration:
                GV = '- bad match -'
        yield '  {!s:15}  {!s:^13}'.format(ma.group(1), GV)

countries = {'Singapore':'SG','Austria':'AU',
             'Swiss':'CH','Chile':'CL',
             'Den LMM':'DN','LMM Den':'LM'}

s = ('  Singapore  SIngapore  SiNgapore  SinGapore'
     '  SI.Ngapore  SIngaPore  SinGaporE  SinGAPore'
     '  SINGaporE  SiNg.aPoR   singapore  sIngapore'
     '  siNgapore  sinGapore  sINgap.ore  sIngaPore'
     '  sinGaporE  sinGAPore  sINGaporE  siNgaPoRe'
     '    Austria    Aus.trIA    aUSTria    AUSTRiA'
     '  Den L.M.M     Den   Lm.M    DEn Lm.M.'
     '  DEN L.MM      De.n L.M.M.     Den LmM'
     '    L.MM   DEn      LMM DeN     LM.m  Den')

print '\n'
print '\n'.join(res for res in code(s,countries))
```

#### EDIT 2

I improved the code. It's shorter and more readable.
The instruction `assert(.....]` is to verify that the keys of the dictionaru are well formed for the purpose.

```
import re

def doot(x):
    return '\.?'.join(ch for ch in x) + '\.?'

def regexize(labels,doot=doot,
             wg2 = '(%s) *( %s)',wnog2 = '(%s)(%s)',
             ri = re.compile('(.(?!.*? )|[^ ]+)( ?) *(.+\Z)')):
    to_join = []
    modlabs = {}
    for K in labels.iterkeys():
        g1,g2,g3 = ri.match(K).groups()
        to_join.append((wg2 if g2 else wnog2)
                       % (doot(g1), doot(g3.lower())))
        modlabs[g1+g2+g3.lower()] = labels[K]
    return (re.compile('|'.join(to_join), re.I), modlabs)



def code(X,labels,regexize = regexize):
    reglab,modlabs = regexize(labels)
    for ma in reglab.finditer(X):
        a,b = tuple(x for x in ma.groups() if x)
        k = (a + b.lower()).replace('.','')
        GV = modlabs[k] if k in modlabs else '- bad match -'
        yield '  {!s:15}  {!s:^13}'.format(a+b, GV)

countries = {'Singapore':'SG','Austria':'AU',
             'Swiss':'CH','Chile':'CL',
             'Den LMM':'DN','LMM Den':'LM'}

assert(all('.' not in k and
          (k.count(' ')==1 or k[0].upper()==k[0])
          for k in countries))

s = ('  Singapore  SIngapore  SiNgapore  SinGapore'
     '  SI.Ngapore  SIngaPore  SinGaporE  SinGAPore'
     '  SINGaporE  SiNg.aPoR   singapore  sIngapore'
     '  siNgapore  sinGapore  sINgap.ore  sIngaPore'
     '  sinGaporE  sinGAPore  sINGaporE  siNgaPoRe'
     '    Austria    Aus.trIA    aUSTria    AUSTRiA'
     '  Den L.M.M     Den   Lm.M    DEn Lm.M.'
     '  DEN L.MM      De.n L.M.M.     Den LmM'
     '    L.MM   DEn      LMM DeN     LM.m  Den')

print '\n'.join(res for res in code(s,countries))
```

Comment: It worked fine. But in the above case for "Singapore" i want to see that "S" is capital and "ingapore" may be small letters or capital letters or both. but above case is only working for "Singapore".  i know that in perl we use regex some thing like this "S" "(?i)ingapore".

Comment: Output should be as Singapore             SG        
  SIngapore             SG  
  SiNgapore             SG  
  SinGapore             SG  
  SINgapore             SG
  SIngaPore             SG
  SinGaporE             SG
  singapore        - bad match -
  sIngapore        - bad match -

Comment: And what must be the result and cases for the items 'Den   Lm.M ', 'LMM DeN',etc.. ?

Comment: For the case 'Den Lm.M' "Den" should be case senstive and "Lm.N" might be in any of the case. for the case of 'LMM DeN' "LMM" should be case sensitive and "De" might be in any of the case and "N" should again be case sensitive.

Comment: What !!? For **'LMM DeN'**, ``LMM`` must be case-sensitive (that's OK, it's what does my code) and ``De`` is accepted in any case but ``N`` should be case-sensitive ?! Why ? In fact, I don't need to know why, I need to know the general rule, not tiny bits of rules adding one after the other, or the process will be everlasting. Please clarify the rules completely.

Comment: By the way, I searched for **LMM** and I found it may be _Los Mochis, Mexico_ airport and I concluded that **Den** is for _Denver_ and that names are locations of airports. Am I right ? Where does the dictionary name:code come from ? Is it a big one or not ?

Comment: @new2python Rather _Los Mochis, Mexic_ than _Los Mochis, Mexico_ because there are 1400 kilometers between Los Mochis and Mexico !

Comment: By mistake i have taken the wrong codes. Now it is working fine. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: OK Thank you. Are you aware that in my code, the dots are not taken in account, which requires that the keys of the dictionary must be written without any dot in them. For example _'L.M.M. Den'_ isn't a good key for my code because when the regex motor will encouter say ``'LM.M'`` the prog will remove the dots before searching for a key, that is to say the program will search for ``LMM`` in the dictionary's keys, not _L.M.M._

Comment: Consequently also, if a name ``SinG.apOre`` is encoutered, it will be accepted by the program because it will perform ``beg[0]+beg[1:].replace('.','').lower()`` with beg == ``SinG.apOre``

Answer (score 5):

As commented, the Ugly way would be:

```
>>> re.search("S[iI][Nn][Gg][Aa][Pp][Oo][Rr][Ee]" , "SingaPore")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10cea84a8>
>>> re.search("S[iI][Nn][Gg][Aa][Pp][Oo][Rr][Ee]" , "Information in sinGapore")
```

The more elegant way would be matching Singapore case-insensitive, and then checking that the first letter is `S`:

```
reg=re.compile("singapore", re.I)

>>> s="Information in sinGapore"
>>> reg.search(s) and reg.search(s).group()[0]=='S'
False

>>> s="Information in SinGapore"
>>> reg.search(s) and reg.search(s).group()[0]=='S'
True
```

### Update

Following your comment - you could use:

```
reg.search(s).group().startswith("S")
```

Instead of:

```
reg.search(s).group()[0]==("S")
```

If it seems more readable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there any other way in writing the same? because think if i has a long string and it might be a problem writing for the whole.

Comment: I think that the `reg.search(s) and reg.search(s).group()[0]=='S'` condition is as readable as it gets.

Comment: @AdamMatan I think you're right - matching all lower, then double checking the first letter is the best way I can think of for Python's re....

Comment: @Adam Matan Thanks for your answer. how can i implement the same using if else loop. for example if it matches singapore i want to set a global vaiable GV to SG elif matches australia set GV to AU and so on...

Answer (score 2):

You could write a simple lambda to generate the ugly-but-all-re-solution:

```
>>> leading_cap_re = lambda s: s[0].upper() + ''.join('[%s%s]' % 
                                                    (c.upper(),c.lower()) 
                                                        for c in s[1:])
>>> leading_cap_re("Singapore")
'S[Ii][Nn][Gg][Aa][Pp][Oo][Rr][Ee]'
```

For multi-word cities, define a string-splitting version:

```
>>> leading_caps_re = lambda s : r'\s+'.join(map(leading_cap_re,s.split()))
>>> print leading_caps_re('Kuala Lumpur')
K[Uu][Aa][Ll][Aa]\s+L[Uu][Mm][Pp][Uu][Rr]
```

Then your code could just be:

```
if re.search(leading_caps_re("Singapore") , st):
    ...etc...
```

and the ugliness of the RE would be purely internal.

Comment: You are not wrong, but the regex is too ugly and unreadable. There are better way to write the regex, with the features supported.

Comment: @nhahtdh - I'm not suggesting that the OP use the literal string created by `leading_caps_re`, but just have the ugly RE string used internally, as shown in my edit.

Comment: I removed my downvote, since I misunderstood how the "flag" group works in `re`. The way it is applied on the whole expression makes it mostly useless.

Answer (score 1):

interestingly

```
/((S)((?i)ingapore))/
```

Does the right thing in perl but doesn't seem to work as needed in python.  To be fair the python docs spell it out clearly, (?i) alters the whole regexp

Answer (score 0):

This is the BEST answer:

```
(?-i:S)(?i)ingapore
```

[ClickHere](https://regex101.com/r/MF1tew/1) for proof: